# How to set font size or bold on description record row on Qweb sale report?

Tags: odoo-11, qweb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><odoo> <data>

 <template id="id_document" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document"> 

 <xpath expr="//tbody[@class='sale_tbody']//tr//td[1]" position="replace"> 

 <t t-esc="layout_category['name']" style="font-weight: bold;"/> 

 </xpath> 

 </template> </data></odoo>
```

the following code doesn't work for me,please any suggestion thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution

```
<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('row','mt32','mb32')]/div[@t-if='doc.user_id.name']/p" position="attributes">
             <attribute name="style">font-weight: bold;color:red;</attribute>
        </xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use style attribute in `<t t-esc>` tag.

If you want to use style attribute then you must need to use any HTML tag like **div, p, span**

Here is an example.

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;"><t t-esc="layout_category['name']"/></span>
```

Try to use above code. Hope it will work fine. Upvote if the suggestion is working.

Comment: Thanks, I was found a solution you may see it below.